# javascript bigger than if statement not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I am no expert in javascript, so hope someone can help me out.

I have the following code, but for some reason it always thinks the statement is true

```
delvNum=document.getElementById("deliveryNum").value;
delvQTY=document.getElementById("delvQTY"+id).value;
orderQTY=document.getElementById("orderQTY"+id).value;

if (delvQTY>orderQTY)
{
  alert("Can't deliver more than " + orderQTY + ", you are trying to deliver " + delvQTY + ". Please fix!");
  document.getElementById("delvQTY"+id).focus();
  return;
}
```

The error message does show the quantity of each var, and is correctly being passed through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings and not numbers.

Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```
if (parseFloat(delvQTY)>parseFloat(orderQTY))
```

or

```
if (parseInt(delvQTY,10)>parseInt(orderQTY,10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a string comparison, not number comparison and, for example, `"9">"1111"` is `true`.

You need to parse your values :

```
if (parseFloat(delvQTY)>parseFloat(orderQTY))
```

See [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure `delvQTY` and `orderQTY` are `Number` before you can do `>` comparison.

`var delvValue = parseInt(delvQTY, 10);` for converting to integers.

Or for floating point numbers: `var delvValue = parseFloat(delvQTY);`

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the string values, rather than numerical ones.  You should say:

```
delvNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("deliveryNum").value, 10);
```

(assume you are dealing with integers, else use `parseFloat`).

Note the `10` to say you're dealing with base 10 - without it, if someone types a leading zero then you'll get baffling results.